# Does Maharal, Maharsha or Zohar discuss the concept of how שָׁלוֹם, שְׁלֵמוּת, שָׁלֵם are associated with one another?

Tags: sources-mekorot, words, hebrew, shalom-peace, maharal

Rav Shimon Schwab writes that the word שָׁלוֹם is related to שְׁלֵמוּת, *completion*, שָׁלֵם, *perfection* (*[on Iyov](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422600900.html)*, page 67)

Does anyone know if the *Maharal, Maharsha* or *Zohar* say such a concept?

Comment: Isn't it simply the fact that they share the same root?

Comment: See berachot 39b  תני תנא קמיה דרב נחמן בר יצחק מניח הפרוסה בתוך השלמה ובוצע ומברך אמר ליה מה שמך א"ל שלמן א"ל שלום אתה ושלמה משנתך ששמת שלום בין התלמידים

Comment: It is just Gemara

Answer (score 4):

The Maharal indeed says in [Nesivos Olam](https://www.sefaria.org/Netivot_Olam%2C_Netiv_Hashalom.1.1?vhe=OYW&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that word Shalom comes from the word Shleimus. This is a major recurring theme in the Maharal

Here is the beginning of the first Perek of Nesiv Hashalom in Nesivos Olam:

> בספר משלי (י"ב) מרמה בלב חורשי רע וליועצי שלום שמחה. שלמה המלך ר"ל כי בני אדם אשר הם חורשי און והם אותם שמשלחים מדנים בין איש ובין חבירו, ונקראים חורשי און כי החורש מכין האדמה עד שתצמיח וכך מכין המשלח מדנים בין בני אדם עד שיצא הריב מביניהם, ויש בלבם מרמה כי אם אין עושים במרמה אינם יכולים לגמור מעשיהם שיחשבו בני אדם כי באולי עושה בשביל שנאה שיש לו על האחד ולכך הוא עושה במרמה (אינם יכולים האדם) עד שיוכל לשלוח מדנים. ונקרא המחלוקת אשר הם עושים בשם רע כי השם הזה הוא דוקא אל המחלוקת, וכמו שאמרו במדרש (ב"ר פ"ד) למה לא נאמר בשני כי טוב מפני שבו נברא המחלוקת, שמזה תדע כי המחלוקת הוא רע והכתוב אומר גם כן עושה שלום ובורא רע, ובודאי הרע הזה הוא המחלוקת שהוא הפך השלום ואם כן המחלוקת הוא רע. ואמר כי ליועצי שלום ראוי אליהם השמחה כאשר השלום הוא השלימות, וכמו שיתבאר עוד איך השלום הוא שלימות הכל והוא נותן המציאות אל הכל, ומפני כך ראוי אל רודפי השלום השמחה כי השמחה הוא כאשר נמצא דבר בשלימות כמו שהאבל על הפסד וחסרון, **וזה בעצמו מה שנקרא שלום שהוא מלשון שלימות כי השלום משלים המציאות עד שנמצא הדבר בשלימות בלי חסרון** ודבר זה יתבאר עוד, ולכך ראוי אל יועצי שלום הרודפים שלום בין איש ובין אחיו שמחה כאשר השמחה היא על השלימות כמו האבל שהוא כאשר יש הפסד והעדר. והמרמה הוא הפך השמחה, כי כאשר האדם הוא בשמחה הוא בשלימות וראוי שיהיה האדם בשלימות כאשר הוא רודף שלום, שעצם השלום הוא השלימות, והפך זה המרמה שהוא דבר של רמאות וכל רמאות הוא שקר ואין לו מציאות, ודבר זה שייך לחורשי און שהם משלחי מדנים בין איש לרעהו שדבר זה הירוס מציאת העולם, ולכך הרמאות והמחלוקת שייכים זה לזה, וכן השמחה שהיא שלימות ראוי אל רודפי שלום שהוא שלימות המציאות. ולפיכך אמר כשם שיש בלב חורשי און מרמה כי המרמה הוא דבר שקר אין לו מציאות וזה שייך לחורשי און, כן ליועצי שלום הרודפים שלום ראוי להם השמחה שהשמחה היא על השלימות כמו שהתבאר, שהשלום משלים המציאות ולכך ראוי להם השמחה כאשר רודפים השלום שהוא שלימות המציאות:
>
> **This is why peace (Shalom) is called in the the language of completeness (Shleymus). Because peace completes all of existence until everything is found to be complete without any lack.**

Comment: @ Silver: thank you!