# Connection between Shalom and Shaleim

Tags: sources-mekorot, shalom-peace

I've heard that there is a connection between "שלום" - "peace" and "שלם" - "complete".

Does anyone know what the source of that is? Thank you so much.

Comment: https://parshaponders.com/nasso-5780/#_ftnref15

Comment: @robev Thank you so much! Those sources are perfect! If you (or anyone else) wants to write this up I will vote for it and accept it BL"N.

Comment: cf https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/104908/170

Answer (score 2):

They share the same Hebrew root (shoresh) - Shin Lamed Mem. So there's a connection between them etymologically. Same shoresh is found in the word לשלם, meaning "to pay" i.e. to "make someone whole".

Answer (score 2):

One source could be culled from the Gemoro in [Kiddushin 66b](https://www.sefaria.org/Kiddushin.66b.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> בעל מום דעבודתו פסולה מנלן אמר רב יהודה אמר שמואל **דאמר קרא (במדבר כה, יב) לכן אמור הנני נותן לו את בריתי שלום כשהוא שלם ולא כשהוא חסר והא שלום כתיב** אמר רב נחמן וי"ו דשלום קטיעה היא
>
> *The Gemara continues its analysis of the baraita. From where do we derive that the service of a blemished priest is retroactively invalid? Rav Yehuda says that Shmuel says: **As the verse states with regard to Pinchas: “Wherefore say: Behold, I give to him My covenant of peace [shalom]” (Numbers 25:12), which means that he receives the covenant when he is whole [shalem], but not when he is blemished and lacking a limb**. The Gemara comments: But shalom is written, rather than shalem. Rav Naḥman says: The letter vav in the word shalom is severed. According to tradition, this letter is written with a break in it, and therefore the word can be read as though the vav were missing.*

(Translation and added notation from Sefaria)